# How can I start the automate program in Python

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to automate pdf file to Quizlet using Python. I have the pdf file with a format like this in the picture. I want to export this data to Quizlet with a question and answer options to words in Quizlet and correct answer to Definitions in Quizlet. I don't know where to start and I would be greatly appreciated if someone can help me where to start and what I need resources to create this automation program. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: @Kijmu7 Other than manually rewriting the text from that form with python, If you are looking to use Optical Character Recognition for extracting the text from the image to use/store elsewhere for Quizlet etc, I would recommend using `tesseract.js`. [tesseract.js homepage](https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/)

Comment: Have you looked at parsing a pdf?